# Is this set a star domain?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-problem, winding-number

Definition:
A set S in $\mathbb{C}$ is called a star domain if there exists an $a \in S$ such that for all $x \in S$, the line segment from a to x is in S. And the point $a \in S$ is called a star center of the star domain.

> a) $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: z\neq x+0i, \textrm{ where } |x|\geq 1\}$

Someone told me that this is a star domain and has a star center, however, I do not really see it. My understanding that it is the line segments that are not joined together. How would I prove existence of a star domain?

The graph is the whole plane excluding 2 line segments y=0 from (1,$\infty)$ and (-1,$\infty$)

Comment: You have drawn $\mathbb{C}-S$ not $S$.

Comment: You are aware that what you drew is the complement of the set $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: z\neq x+0i \ where |x|\geq 1\}$?

Comment: Why did you tag this with `integration`, `complex-analysis`, `cauchy-problem`, and `winding-number`?

Comment: The origin is a star centre for the set.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott ah i see, how would i prove the existence of it being a star centre? Do i basically state that any point in S and the origin that is joined by a line segment lies in the domain, S?

Comment: @pop: Yes, though you can and should do more than just state it: you can actually describe the segments and demonstrate that they lie in $S$. For instance, for any point $\langle a,b\rangle$ with $a>0$ and $b\ne 0$ it’s just $$\left\{\left\langle x,\frac{bx}a\right\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:0\le x\le a\right\}\,.$$